# Positioning a popover with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a popover like this; when the user hovers on first image he sees second image on popover.

`<img src="myimage.jpg" rel="mypop" data-content="&lt;img src=&quot; otherimage.jpg &quot;&gt;">`

I use this in script tags

`$("[rel=mypop]").popover({ placement:'right', html : true });`

Everything is ok image is in the middle of page.
But if the user hovers to an image in **upper or downer side of page**, he can't see proper image.

To solve this issue I suppose I must use CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    img[rel="mypop"] {
    }
</style>
```

But I couldn't find what to write into CSS style to show user popover in proper place.

I want user to see popover without conflicting any parts of page.

[image]

Comment: sounds like a problem with absolute positioning, though without seeing the code, i can't help ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Twitter Bootstrap popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) for this.
But I found out that, using popover (for showing images) is not suitable.
So now I use Colorbox to show that kind of data.